# Visual Basic why is there an Object error?

Tags: excel, vba

There is some kind of error(424). That occurs when i try to select a specific sheet.

I tried to initialize inside the if statement and/or inside the Do-Until loop.

```
Dim wbMnTbl As Workbook

cin = InputBox("input Data in form of Excel sheet names", Number)

Pfad1 = "PATH&" & cin & "\" & cin & ".xlsx"
Set wbMnTbl = Workbooks.Open(Pfad1)

Do
    If IsEmpty(Cells(ZelleA1, ZelleA2)) = False Then
        SelA = (Cells(ZelleA1, ZelleA2).Select)
        Selection.Copy

        'MsgBox wbMnTb1.Sheet("Sheet-Name").Range("B3")

        'Error is in this Line 
        -> wbMnTb1.Sheets("Sheet-Name").Range("B" & VarA).Select <-
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        wbMnTbl.Close    
        ZelleA1 = ZelleA1 + 1
        VarA = VarA + 1
    Else
        H = 1   
    End If
Loop Until H = 1
```

Comment: You probably don't have a sheet named "Sheet-Name".

Comment: What is the initial value of `VarA`? If it is `0` then keep in mind that there is no cell `B0` - and you should define that variable and use `Option Explicit` as well to avoid problems like this.

Comment: theses are placeholders. path/Sheet-Name/input...

Comment: You have a typo... `wbMnTb1` and `wbMnTbl`

Comment: Please use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code.

Comment: The problem is that it isnt even accepting wbMnTb1. 
It says Objekt needed.

Comment: It should be `wbMnTbl` and not `wbMnTb1`

Comment: Thanks it was the typo... now it throws a automation error

Comment: Yes you will have to work with objects. Avoid the use of `.Select/.ActiveSheet` etc. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `VarA` in `wbMnTb1.Sheets("Sheet-Name").Range("B" & VarA).Select` is not populated when that line is executed. That results in a nonsense range string.

I advise you to declare all of your variables. That way you're also confined to only using integers for the VarA variable, thereby preventing you from passing strings to it. After all, `VarA` should be a row number. The best practice for this is to use `Option Explicit`

Furthermore, other variables are also empty when you refer to them. Not sure what you mean to do but in order to work with variables it would help actually populating them before them.

**For example**
This prints nothing

```
Debug.Print myVar
```

This prints `0` because `Long` is an integer and it's not populated beforehand, so it prints the standard value of an integer variable

```
Dim myVar As Long
Debug.Print myVar
```

This prints `1`, because you set it to that value

```
Dim myVar As Long
myVar = 1
Debug.Print myVar
```

This results in an error. You cannot pass a string to a number type variable

```
Dim myVar As Long
myVar = "test" 'ERROR
Debug.Print myVar
```

Your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub MySub()
Dim wbMnTbl As Workbook
Dim cin As String, Pfad1 As String
Dim VarA As Long, ZelleA1 As Long, ZellaA2 As Long, H As Long, Number As Long
Dim SelA As Range

'Variable Number is 0
cin = InputBox("input Data in form of Excel sheet names", Number)

Pfad1 = "PATH&" & cin & "\" & cin & ".xlsx"
Set wbMnTbl = Workbooks.Open(Pfad1)

Do
    'Variable ZelleA1, ZelleA2, VarA, H are 0 on the first loop
    If IsEmpty(wbMnTbl.Cells(ZelleA1, ZelleA2)) = False Then
        Set SelA = wbMnTbl.Cells(ZelleA1, ZelleA2)
        SelA.Copy wbMnTbl.Sheets("Sheet-Name").Range("B" & VarA)

        wbMnTbl.Close    
        ZelleA1 = ZelleA1 + 1
        VarA = VarA + 1
    Else
        H = 1   
    End If
Loop Until H = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: You also copied the typo across :D

Comment: Can the `1` and `l` be any more similar? @SiddharthRout